# Apostrophes not displaying correctly

Tags: php, html, mysql

I’m making a simple blog with PHP, MYSQL and HTML. I have a problem while displaying apostrophes and quotes, instead of displaying "example" (in a html page) it displays \"example\", I’m using escape string and all that but it is still not working :(
The page:

```
<?php
    $servidor = "XX";
    $bd = "XX";
    $usuario = "XX";
    $senha = "XX";

    mysql_connect($servidor, $usuario, $senha) or trigger_error(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db('a3722962_main') or trigger_error(mysql_error());

    $tutoID = $_GET['tuto'];

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tutorials WHERE id = '$tutoID'");

    while($line = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        $content          = $line['text'];
        $title            = $line['title'];
        $creator          = $line['creator'];
        $name             = $line['name'];
        $idtest           = $line['id'];
    }
    {echo "$content";}
?>
```

The posting page:

```
<?php
    mysql_connect($servidor, $usuario, $senha) or trigger_error(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db('a3722962_main') or trigger_error(mysql_error());

    $usuario = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['UsuarioNome']);
    $title = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['title']);
    $post = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['post']);
    $realname = $_SESSION['usuario'];
    $lang = $_POST['lang'];
    $cat = $_POST['cat'];
    $dopost = "INSERT INTO tutorials VALUES ('', '$title', '$post', '$usuario', '$realname', NOW( ), '$cat', '$lang')";

    if($title == "" or $post == "") {
        echo "<script>alert(Please, fill out the damn form...);
        location.href='inside' </script>";
    } else {
        echo "<script>alert(Your post probably has been added!); 
        location.href='inside'</script>";
    }

    if (!empty($_POST) AND (empty($post) OR empty($title))) {
        echo "<script>alert('Please fill out the damn posting form.'); 
        location.href='inside'</script>";
    } else {
        $query = mysql_query($dopost);
    };

    if($query) {
        echo "<script>alert('The post that you have just setup has been added successfully! :D');
        location.href='inside'</script>";
    } else {
        echo "Could not add this post to the database.";
        echo mysql_error();
    } 
?>
```

Thanks all!

Comment: **You are leaving yourself wide open to SQL injection.** Please learn about using parametrized queries, preferably with the PDO module, to protect your web app.   http://bobby-tables.com/php has examples to get you started.

Comment: Have a look at magic quotes, older versions of php may have this turned on still, it has been removed from the latest version of php. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-magic-quotes-gpc.php

Comment: use PDO forget the mysql extension.

Answer (score 0):

Call [`stripslashes`](https://www.php.net/stripslashes)

```
echo stripslashes($content);
```

Comment: @user2676456 No worries, please consider clicking the tick icon under the vote arrows to mark this answer as accepted for future viewers of this question